# What does round(value, 2) do?

Tags: python, rounding

I am currently participating in a free online course through MIT OCW. I was given a certain problem and I am trying to understand the solution. I am not sure what the "2" is doing. it is the two in the (minMonthlyPaymentRate * balance, 2) Here is the solution:

```
# 6.00 PS1-A Solution
# Determines remaining credit card balance after a year of making the minimum payment each month

balance = float(raw_input("Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: "))
annualInterestRate = float(raw_input("Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: "))
minMonthlyPaymentRate = float(raw_input("Enter the minimum monthly payment rate as a decimal: "))

# Monthly Interest Rate
monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12

# Initialize state variables
numMonths = 1
totalAmtPaid = 0

while numMonths <= 12:
    # Minimum monthly payment of balance at start of the month
    minPayment = round(minMonthlyPaymentRate * balance,2)**This Two!?**
    totalAmtPaid += minPayment

    # Amt of monthly payment that goes to interest
    interestPaid = round(monthlyInterestRate * balance,2)

    # Amt of principal paid off
    principalPaid = minPayment - interestPaid

    # Subtract monthly payment from outstanding balance
    balance -= principalPaid

    print "Month:", numMonths
    print "Minimum monthly payment:", minPayment
    print "Remaining balance:", balance

    # Count this as a new month     
    numMonths += 1

print "RESULT"
print "Total amount paid:",totalAmtPaid
print "Remaining balance:",balance
```

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) it rounds to the number of digits, in this case 2

Comment: its just saying the result should be rounded to two decimal places...

Comment: And you were not able to find this in the documentation yourself?

Comment: Can you reduce the example to one line?

Answer (score 1):

`round()` which rounds off to the given number of digits and returns the floating point number.

Example code:

```
val=2.665
print(round(val, 2);

output:
6.67
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [python documentation of the function round()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) it states "rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point". So it means the result will be rounded to two digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

#### One picture is worth a thousand words.

[image]